# Next.js with basePath not rendering the images with nginx deployment

Tags: nginx, next.js, nextjs-image

I have deployed my Next.js app on Ubuntu 16.0.4 with nginx.

I already have an app deployed on the root `mywebsite.com` which is working fine. I'm trying deploy this app with a `basePath` at `mywebsite.com/some-keyword`.

The app seems to work fine but not rendering the images.

How can I fix this?

Nginx updates:

```
location /some-keyword {
  proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

  # First attempt to serve request as file, then
  # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
  # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

`next.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  basePath: '/some-keyword'
};
```

Using `next/image` like so:

```js
<Image src='/img/alert-down.png' width={550} height={320} />
```

Comment: What do you see in the Network tab in dev tools for the images requests? Are they 404ing?

Comment: I have also tried `https://mywebsite.com/_next/image?url=params` but it also didn't work

Comment: Are you using `next/image` component by any chance? Can you share some code of how you're setting an image?

Comment: Yeah using `next/image` like so `<Image src='/img/alert-down.png' width={550} height={320} />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Next.js [Base Path docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/basepath#images):

> When using the `next/image` component, you will need to add the `basePath` in front of `src`.

In your case, assuming your `basePath` is `/some-keyword` your code should look like:

```js
<Image src='/some-keyword/img/alert-down.png' width={550} height={320} />
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `next.config.js` add the following:

```
images: {
    domains: ['yourdomain.com'],
    unoptimized: true,
},
```

This helped me resole some of my image loading problems on Ubuntu 20.04 running NGINX server.